# How to analyze それが元で?

Tags: grammar, syntax

I understand the meaning of this phrase, but I have a hard time understanding how it's constructed.

In phrases like それで or というわけで you have a noun plus the particle で. This looks superficially similar, except that それが元(です) is a sentence, not a noun (or noun phrase).

What's going on here? Is there a bunch of other stuff being left unspoken?

Comment: any context for where you're seeing it?

Comment: I have read this question several times and am thinking either the answer should already be obvious to you, or I don't understand what you're asking. Do you realize that you can have practically any sentence ending in で and then follow it by another sentence?

Comment: aren't they different types of で? particle-で and conjunction-で (which I understood was a shortened version of です)

Comment: They're both the same; they're both the -て form of だ/です/である. There's a different で that's a particle, but that means something completely different.

Comment: Is this part of a conversation? If so could you post the conversation in its entirety?

Comment: For me it's the same difference between saying "That is the cause" and "(With) that being the cause..."

Answer (score 3):

Might be worthwhile rendering it into partial English:

```
So, with that as the 元, ...
```

And 元 can mean foundation, start, beginning, entranceway, original,... it could be rendered many ways.

Essentially, this construction requires that there be a preceding sentence/clause/word to point to. (それが)

You could also see it as

```
それが元となって, or それを元として, ...
```

So you're wondering if it's related to それで or というわけで

Kind-of.  というわけで is literally "by way of the [mentioned] reason" or "for that reason" in more natural English.  The で in the phrase you posted can also be interpreted as "by way of [this] 元... (something occurred) "

Well you asked this over a month ago, but I wrote out this response so, I'll post it in case it's useful to someone down the line.

Comment: We do not say 「それが元として」 (and it was over a year ago when this question was asked).

Comment: well, sorry for trying to participate, I just hit the Unaswered button and gave it my best shot.  Yeah, it should be sore WO moto to shite, my bad.

Comment: By the way, answering old questions is totally okay―it doesn't matter if the question was asked over a year ago.

Comment: ["Bumping" old questions is perfectly acceptable, **and even encouraged**, when you have something new to contribute.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125967) And old/unanswered questions even get bumped by the software every now and then.

Comment: Such as it did by [the software](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) right now.